# Change Woocommerce cart page title text

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to change the cart page title text from "Cart" to "My Cart"

The html shows as:

```
<header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">Cart</h1></header>
```

This code is being outputed by the:

```
<header class="entry-header">
<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );?>
</header>
```

I dont know where woocommerce/wordpress stores the text "cart" that is injected into the above code by the function the_title()

I was thinking the solution might be to use the function is_cart() to change the title to my preferred text if user is on cart page, but my PHP skills not taking me further. Cheers.

Comment: It's the page title. Go to Pages, and under Pages find the "Cart" page. Change the title to anything you like.

Comment: @helgatheviking I feel so stupid for such a simple issue. Thanks mate

Comment: Everyone get's a #facepalm now and then.

Comment: how to add translation of it? woocommerce.po - mo does not work